# Qual a diferença de DLL e lib?

Tags: c, c++, dll, biblioteca, lib

Sei que `.dll` e `.lib` são bibliotecas, a primeira é dinâmica e a segunda é estática. Mas o que isso realmente quer dizer? Como cada uma funciona?

Se eu tiver que gerar uma biblioteca a partir de um código, o que eu devo ter em mente para decidir se eu faço uma `.dll` ou uma `.lib`?

Comment: ve se isso te ajuda http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-lib-and-dll/

Answer (score 36, accepted):

## Conceituação inicial

Aplicação e executável são coisas diferentes. Aplicação é um conjunto de coisas (eventualmente pode ser só o executável quando é algo muito simples), de funções, tarefas, atividades que beneficiam o usuário, é um conceito mais abstrato. Quando um executável principal (EXE no Windows) precisa de uma DLL ele já não representa sozinho a aplicação. Se sem a DLL a aplicação não funciona, se o executável tem dependências, a aplicação certamente não se confunde com o executável.

## Comparação

| DLL | LIB |
| --- | --- |
| Vários arquivos executáveis | Um arquivo monolítico |
| DLL/Dependency Hell | Incompatibilidades entre bibliotecas |
| Aplicações no geral ficam maiores | Executável fica maior |
| Permite carregar códigos não previstos | Tudo que for necessário precisa estar no executável |
| Não permite certas otimizações | Otimizações globais são possíveis |
| Carga mais lenta pera mapear todos os símbolos | Carga mais rápida, todos os vínculos estão prontos |
| Pode ser usada livremente com LGPL | Precisa de uma licença comercial ou mais liberal |
| Permite reusa de binários distribuídos | Duplica binária comum durante o build |
| Melhor interação com ferramentas de terceiros | Só interage se a ferramenta gera executável custom |
| Permite injeção de código malicioso facilmente | Dificulta injeção de código malicioso |
| Permite um binário canônico | Risco de confusão entre versões |

Alguns itens dependem da forma como a biblioteca é criada/usada.

## Biblioteca estática

Uma biblioteca estática não pode ser usada por uma aplicação diretamente, não pode ser executada. Ela é usada para gerar um executável (EXE, DLL) de uma aplicação. Ela é necessária para o processo de montagem do executável, o que frequentemente chamamos de [tempo de compilação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/332635/101) (embora tecnicamente isto seja feito após a compilação propriamente dita).

A biblioteca é composta por diversos arquivos chamados objetos que são gerados pelo compilador. Na verdade é possível inserir estes objetos na aplicação mesmo sem a existência da LIB que é uma forma de agrupar e facilitar o trabalho de construção da aplicação. Estes arquivos são **unidades de compilação**. Existem utilitários para administrar estes arquivos na LIB.

[image: processo de compilação/linkedição]
[image: Onde o linker entra]

Quando você usa uma função de uma destas unidades de compilação todo o objeto é incluso no executável (que pode ser chamado de monolítico se não depende de nada externo).

**Os objetos que não possuem funções referenciadas por sua aplicação não entram** mesmo que eles tenham sido indicados para seleção durante a *linkedição*. O processo de *linkedição* é inteligente neste aspecto. A vinculação (*binding*) da função com a aplicação é feita em tempo de *linkedição* ao contrário da biblioteca dinâmica onde isso é feito em tempo de execução.

Note que o termo correto é "tempo de *linkedição*" e não "tempo de compilação". As bibliotecas são montadas ou vinculadas à uma aplicação após o código já ter sido compilado.

Em bibliotecas bem construídas os objetos devem conter apenas funções que devem ser usadas obrigatoriamente juntas, como os métodos de uma classe, por exemplo.

## Biblioteca dinâmica

Uma DLL/SO é um executável independente em um arquivo independente. É possível até mesmo executá-la como um executável normal sob certas circunstâncias. Nela também tem esses objetos (são binários).

A definição de quais objetos estão lá é responsabilidade de quem construiu a DLL (ou SO, falo mais em DLL para simplificar), assim como em um executável normal. **A DLL pode conter muita coisa que sua aplicação não precisa** e o executável não chama. E se a(s) DLL(s) não contiver(em) tudo que sua aplicação precisa, você terá problemas durante a execução.

A não ser que esteja usando o .NET, onde as DLLs funcionam de forma especial já que não são códigos nativos, não é possível administrar o conteúdo depois que o arquivo for gerado.

Uma DLL tende a ser maior por causa destes possíveis códigos desnecessários que são pré-vinculados e porque ela precisa de informações adicionais para efetuar a chamada dinâmica. Isto nem sempre é uma grande desvantagem mas é bom ter isso em conta.

É possível usar uma técnica de carga sob demanda que permite que uma DLL que não seja efetivamente usada pela aplicação em uma execução específica não seja carregada na memória.

Mas uma DLL específica não pode carregar apenas as funções que serão usadas pela aplicação, até porque ela nem sabe o que será usado. É tudo ou nada (na verdade em nível mais baixo isso não é bem assim, mas é um controle da [memória virtual](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/203928/101) e não dos objetos).

Dado o problema de [DLL Hell](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inferno_de_DLLs) ([em inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell)) e [dependência](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inferno_de_depend%C3%AAncias) ([em inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell)) cada vez mais frequente, as vantagens da DLL ficam cada vez menores já que para solucionar estes problemas costuma-se evitar o reuso do binário e opta-se pela distribuição das DLLs necessárias junto com o executável principal.

No fim temos a DLL só porque todo mundo faz assim. Eu vivo falando que os desenvolvedores, especialmente os mais novos, não pensam no todo, seguem fórmulas.

Além disso, conforme já foi dito, algumas otimizações não são possíveis nestas condições a não ser que o código execute em uma máquina virtual (.NET, Java) que normalmente prepara o ambiente e faz as últimas otimizações em tempo de execução (o que tem um custo).

No .NET a vinculação é feita em tempo de execução - feito pelo [JITter](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/146250/101) - o que torna **possível** fazer algumas otimizações até melhores do que o [*linkeditor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) estático faria. É um processo semelhante ao do Java. O [.NET Native](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) permitirá binários, obviamente nativos, monolíticos.

## Guia de escolha pela DLL

- Sua aplicação usa alguma API externa que só está disponível por DLL ou há alguma praticidade real em optar pela DLL.
- Você tem a opção de *linkagem* estática ou dinâmica mas a licença que você precisa só permite a dinâmica ([Qt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(software)) por exemplo que usa [LGPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Lesser_General_Public_License)).
- A aplicação precisa de flexibilidade e tem um sistema de *plugin* nela que utiliza **códigos executáveis** que podem ser chamados no processo vinculando o código novo ao executável principal.
- *Linkar* estaticamente duas bibliotecas está causando algum conflito ou dificuldade e dinamicamente resolve.
- Você está produzindo algo que deve ser usado com uma aplicação que espera uma DLL. Pode ser porque aquele código precisa ser garantidamente único entre aplicações ou terceiros precisam disto (uso com outra linguagem) ou ainda é um *plugin*.
- Sua aplicação faz parte de uma solução maior ou uma gama ampla de produtos que costumam ser instalados na mesma máquina e tem muitas partes em comum. Pense um pouco mais se deve usar DLL ou não. Eu tendo a não usar. Hoje o reuso do binário é um argumento fraco na maioria dos casos.

Muitas vezes o benefício não compensa o prejuízo, estamos no século XXI, não temos os mesmos problemas do século passado. Ou seja, opte pela DLL/SO quando você não tem outra opção ou está tendo um problema difícil de ser solucionado de outra forma.

## Conclusão

**O uso de DLL tende deixar a aplicação maior e mais lenta**. Apesar de que isto não seja um grande problema na maior parte dos casos. O uso de DLL pode dar a falsa impressão que a aplicação fica menor baseada no tamanho do executável principal. Mas a aplicação é mais do que ele.

Se puder escolher, a primeira opção deveria ser o uso de biblioteca estática e só se houver um motivo específico para usar a biblioteca dinâmica é que ela deveria ser escolhida.

Um único executável facilita a manutenção, depuração, implantação e diagnóstico sem falar na confiabilidade da aplicação que tem menos dependências após construída como já citado nesta e outra resposta.

Mas se for necessário ter uma biblioteca dinâmica, deixe para usar só onde é necessário. Ou seja, dá para fazer um misto. Uma forma não impede a outra. Crie um executável principal com o máximo de código embutido e use arquivos auxiliares no que for estritamente necessário, com isto você diminui a superfície de risco.

Enfim, o assunto é amplo, dá para fazer dezenas de perguntas e não esgotar tudo o que tem para falar.

[Artigo na Wikipedia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biblioteca_(computa%C3%A7%C3%A3o)) ([em inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29)).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: `O uso de DLL tende deixar a aplicação maior e mais lenta`, a aplicação não deveria ficar menor? Pois o executável não incorpora a biblioteca em seu binário. Ou com "aplicação" você queria dizer "biblioteca"? E tem um typo: "disgnóstico".

Comment: Não, este é um erro clássico. Nos detalhes a resposta mostra que ocorre o oposto. A DLL faz parte da aplicação. O máximo que pode acontecer é dar a ilusão dela estar menor na distribuição dela **se** você puder ter certeza que a DLL apropriada já está no computador do usuário. Você pode garantir isto? Não. Então tem que mandar ela junto. Se estiver você pode usá-la ao invés de instalar a sua que é igual, mas corre o risco do DLL Hell. Você acha que isto deixa a aplicação menor? Tem algum ganho? Espaço em disco era problema no século passado. Na memória que é o mais importante c/ ctz fica maior

Comment: Entendi, então: `código+dll` > `código+lib`. A diferença é que quando usa a `lib` o `exe` fica maior, quando usa a `dll` a distribuição fica maior. Correto? É que por "aplicação" eu estava entendendo como `exe`. Agora acho que ficou claro para mim.

Comment: O que pode acontecer na memória é a carga acontecer de forma atrasada e por algum momento não consumir a memória mas quando a DLL carregar provavelmente carregará coisas que a aplicação não precisa. É verdade que se **dependendo** de como a aplicação for feita, se você não usar determinada função, a DLL não será carregada. Eu entendi sua comparação mas para conceitar certo `exe+dll > monolithic exe`. A `lib` faz parte do exe, ela não pode ser dissociada. O `exe` fica maior, e daí se ele precisa e outras coisas? Não adianta ganhar um brinde e pagar o todo mais caro do que se comprasse o brinde.

Comment: trabalhei a um tempo atras em um sistema que registra as `dll` como objeto COM no servidor de aplicação e os terminais de aplicação se conectavam via RPC nesse servidor, acho que hoje os programadores estão mais preocupados em separar em camadas para seguir algum design patterns do que realmente usufruir do uso da `DLL` como uma  biblioteca para ser usada uma unica vez em todas as aplicações que foram publicadas no servidor.

Comment: confesso que sou um desses, pois no mesmo servidor, tenho o mesmo sistema rodando para clientes diferentes e para cada instância do sistema, tenho as mesmas `DLLs` que poderiam ter sida registras no windows e serem compartilhadas entre os sistemas

Answer (score 14):

Ambas tem a mesma finalidade: são bibliotecas que permitem reutilizar um determinado código. Uma é estática (`*.lib`, `*.a`) e a outra dinâmica (`*.dll` ou `*.so`). Isso você já sabe.

Mas as diferenças são:

- As bibliotecas estáticas aumentam o tamanho do binário gerado, pois elas são "embutidas" ao seu próprio código. Enquanto as dinâmicas são armazenadas em um arquivo a parte e são carregadas em tempo de execução.
- Um programa pode carregar um biblioteca dinâmica de uma versão diferente da original, o que permite que você atualize apenas a biblioteca sem ter que recompilar o código principal. O que é bom, mas tem que tomar alguns cuidados ([DLL Hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell) ou [Dependency hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_hell)).
- Como as bibliotecas estáticas são incluídas ao binário do programa principal, é possível que o compilador execute otimizações entre o seu código e o código da biblioteca.
- Em comparação com as estáticas, as bibliotecas dinâmicas consomem um tempo para serem carregadas (isso na maioria dos casos não é problema). E algumas funções, que poderiam ter sido otimizadas, não são (otimizadas para inline, por exemplo).
- Vários programas diferentes podem reutilizar a mesma biblioteca dinâmica.
- As dlls das bibliotecas dinâmicas devem ser distribuídas junto com o programa principal, no caso das estáticas isso não é necessário.
- Há questões legais que exigem o uso de bibliotecas dinâmicas em vez de estáticas. Por xemplo: códigos licenciados em LGPL podem ser utilizadas para fins proprietários, mas apenas em forma de biblioteca dinâmica.
- Uma biblioteca dinâmica escrita em C ou C++ pode ser reutilizada em um programa escrito em outra linguagens. Por exemplo, python pode usar uma dll feita em C utilizando o módulo ctypes.

Comment: Python só consegue usar uma biblioteca em C se for dinâmica? As linguagens que eu uso que permitem o uso destas bibliotecas podem montar executáveis que incluem as bibliotecas C.

Comment: `Vários programas diferentes podem reutilizar a mesma biblioteca dinâmica.` você quer dizer que uma única biblioteca dinâmica pode ser acessada por vários programas **ao mesmo tempo**, correto? Enquanto a lib, é carregada na memória embutida no executável principal, por consequência não pode ser acessada por outros programas. Pois "reutilizável", as duas bibliotecas são: `Ambas tem a mesma finalidade: são bibliotecas que permitem reutilizar um determinado código`

Comment: @Math Várias aplicações podem acessar a mesma DLL ao mesmo tempo. Esta é uma vantagem. Mas cada vez é mais difícil isto realmente acontecer e só costuma acontecer em DLLs muito estáveis que fazem parte do sistema operacional. O reuso não é uma das melhores vantagens da DLL hoje em dia. O reuso neste caso é do **binário final**. Pense bem, isto ajudava quando os computadores mal passavam de bem poucos MB e os HDDs mal chegavam aos GBs. O ganho hoje é irrisório na maioria dos casos e a prática mostrou que é comum nem ter esse ganho. DLL criou um problema e para solucioná-lo criou-se outro.

Answer (score 9):

Resumidamente, uma `DLL` é uma biblioteca que contém funções, as quais podem ser chamadas em tempo de execução pela aplicação, dando assim um dinamismo no seu uso. 
Já a `LIB` é uma biblioteca estática podendo seus métodos só serem invocados em tempo de compilação.
Logo o uso de `LIB` resultaria em um arquivo maior, que poderiam ser divididos com o uso de `DLLs`, tornando assim as `DLLs` mais reutilizáveis, mas em contra partida o uso de `DLLs` tem-se um problema com o seu versionamento.

O dinamismo do uso da `DLL` está ligado ao fato de a mesma `DLL` proporcionar um compartilhamento entre diferentes programas em execução.

Tempo de execução ou runtime (termo em inglês), é o período em que um programa de computador permanece em execução. O termo runtime também pode se referir a uma máquina virtual que gerencia um programa escrito em uma linguagem de computador enquanto está sendo executado.

O termo tempo de execução é um contraponto ao termo tempo de compilação, que é uma referência ao período em que o código é compilado para gerar um programa executável.

**Vantagens DLL**

A lista a seguir descreve algumas das vantagens que são fornecidas quando um programa usa uma DLL:

- Usa menos recursos: Quando vários programas usam a mesma biblioteca de funções, uma DLL pode reduzir a duplicação de código que é carregado no disco e na memória física.
- Promove a arquitetura modular: Uma DLL ajuda a promover a desenvolver programas modulares.
- Instalação e implantação de atenuações: Quando uma função em uma DLL precisa de uma correção ou uma atualização, a implantação e a instalação da DLL não requer o programa a ser vinculados novamente com a DLL.

**Resumindo**
Ao usar `LIB` ao final da compilação tudo fará parte de um executável, com a utilização da `DLL` tem-se uma fragmentação dos módulos do executável, podendo esses módulos serem utilizados após a compilação do executável.

Fonte: http://www.differencebetween.net/technology/difference-between-lib-and-dll/

Comment: Por que a função chamada em tempo de execução dá dinamismo? O que significa `uma função ser chamada em tempo de execução` e `um método ser invocado em tempo de compilação`? No final das contas o executável não vai usar os dois tipos de bibliotecas do mesmo jeito? A única diferença é o tamanho maior do executável quando usa lib? Por que a dll é mais reutilizável que a lib?

Comment: @Math toda função é chamada em tempo de execução e método "nunca" é invocado em tempo de compilação (até tem algo raramente usada e não faz diferença para essa pergunta), provavelmente é só o uso errado de nomenclatura. O que ele talvez tenha tentado falar é quando ocorre a vinculação da função. Editei minha resposta para refletir isto.

Comment: @Math, nesse caso tempo de execução é o de execução do compilador e não do programa.

Comment: Dei uma editada na minha resposta com base em mais conteudo que estudei sobre o assunto.