# Qmake - Executável independente

Tags: c++, qt

Como faço para compilar um programa(.pro) do Qt Creator com "link estático"?
Compilei pelo QT Creator, mas preciso copiar cerca de 6 dlls para a pasta da executável, algumas delas têm mais de 100mb.
Eu li na [documentação](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Build_Standalone_Qt_Application_for_Windows), mas não entendi direito como faz. Vi também algumas perguntas aqui no SO, mas nenhuma esclareceu bem.

Comment: Gabriel só as DLLs de debug pesam, as de release são bem mais leves

Comment: Ainda sim, chega a mais de 40 mb.

Comment: Infelizmente sim, na maioria dos casos o tamanho do seu projeto vai ficar 100mb, compactado com 7z (para criar um instalador) deve ficar uns 33mb aproximadamente. Hoje em dia é difícil ter softwares com menos de 100mb depois de instalado.

Comment: O problema é que é uma aplicação sem nada, apenas um formulário(qt) e um header(1kb). No visual studio, isso seria em torno de 4mb, com as bibliotecas.

Comment: Gabriel talevz tenha copiando dll a mais, tente a minha resposta por favor... Feliz natal (eu nem comemoro isso rs)

Comment: Se eu entendi o que você chama de *link* estático. Você não pode fazer isto sem comprar a licença comercial. Tecnicamente é possível mas não é legal. Eu acho um exagero os 100MB que o @GuilhermeNascimento falou (não que não seja possível todo esse tamanho) mas não espere uma aplicação GUI ter menos do que alguns poucos megabytes, *linkada* estática ou dinamicamente. De fato confirmo que pelo que imagino que você está fazendo, ou seja, testes muito simples, se estiver usando mais que 2 ou 3 DLLs, acho que tem algo errado.

Comment: @bigown concordo, exagerei mesmo, é que anda meio difícil ver aplicativos com menos de 20mb, realmente foi um engano meu, porém com QT não consegui menos de 40mb (ao menos com MingW). Obrigado pela informação sobre o *link*.

Comment: Qualquer Hello World em GUi vai ficar com alguns MB. De fato *linkar* estaticamente pode diminuir um pouco o tamanho (falo disto [nessa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44347/101), mas parece que poucas pessoas entendem isto) mas não espere milagres principalmente porque a Qt tem muitas dependências e a forma da compilação também pode não ajudar muito.

Comment: @bigown estou lendo, acho que começo a entender, irei estudar. Obrigado por está resposta. Eu editei a resposta e coloquei uma referencia ao seu link. Obrigado mais uma vez! Feliz natal

Comment: A distribuição usando o Qt realmente fica grande sem linkagem estática, mas seu programa vai funcionar standalone, utilizando outros frameworks como .NET ou as bibliotecas do Java eles ficam pequenos mas porque o usuário já tem as bibliotecas no computador dele. Você pode utilizar o [UPX](http://upx.sourceforge.net/) para tentar reduzir o tamanho dos binários finais.

Comment: Você não precisa de todas as DLLs, somente as que usa de fato na sua aplicação. Tou achando muito exagerada essa quantidade de dados que você menciona, nunca consegui chegar nem na metade disso com distribuição completa de aplicativo em Qt.

Answer (score 1):

### Customizando o ICU

As DLLs do [ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/download) realmente são pesadas, principalmente a `icudt5*.dll`

Porém existe uma maneira de customizar esta DLL usando o [ICU Data Library Customizer](http://apps.icu-project.org/datacustom/), assim sendo possível reduzir bastante o seu tamanho, como citado no [fórum do Qt](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/38489/)

Exemplos reduzidos:

- [ICU para Qt 5.2](http://qlcplus.sourceforge.net/icudt51.dll)
- [ICU para Qt 5.3](http://qlcplus.sourceforge.net/icudt52.dll)

### Usando o Dependency Walker

Um recurso que você pode utilizar para detectar as DLLs necessárias no seu projeto é o [**Dependency Walker**](http://www.dependencywalker.com/), ele irá lhe ajudar a detectar apenas as dlls necessárias, usando:

1. O mais importante antes de tudo é que você deve renomear a pasta `/Qt/QtX.X.X` para algo como `/Qt/QtX.X.X-tmp`, pois algumas DLLs podem estar "registradas"
2. Inicialmente a pasta com o seu EXE não deve possuir nenhuma DLL exceto a `Qt5Core` e a `Qt5Gui`
3. Abra o `depends.exe`
4. Arraste e solte o aplicativo compilado (em modo Release) do seu projeto na janela do "Depency Walker"
5. Copie as DLLs que geralmente aparecem em amarelo no `depends.exe` (algumas não são ausência, pode ser algum erro, como uma DLLs para x64 em um projeto x86)

Note que no Windows é necessário copiar uma pasta que está dentro da pasta "/Qt/plugins" chamada `platforms` e apenas uma DLL é necessária (acredito eu), a `qwindows.dll`

Ficando algo como (MingW):

```
./platforms/qwindows.dll (1mb)
./icudt53.dll (21mb)
./icuin53.dll (3mb)
./icuuc53.dll (2mb)
./libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll (118kb)
./libstdc++-6.dll (1mb)
./libwinpthread-1.dll (48kb)
./Qt5Core.dll (4mb)
./Qt5Gui.dll (5mb)
./Qt5Widgets.dll (6mb)
./app.exe
```

### Desabilitando recursos

Você pode [desabilitar alguns recursos](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/configure-options.html), como o OpenGL e o ICU no Qt setando a *flag* `-no-icu` e `-no-opengl`, para fazer isto é necessário usar o `configure.exe`, segue o link [Como compilar a versão estática do Qt para Windows com GCC](http://qt-project.org/wiki/How_to_build_a_static_Qt_version_for_Windows_with_gcc) (este link fornece a orientação de como usar o `configure.exe` para configurar a opções desejadas)

Outras opções que você pode tentar

- `-no-accessibility` Não compila a acessibilidade "Windows Active Accessibility"
- `-no-stl` Não compila STL.
- `-no-sql-<driver>` Desabilita SQL  inteiramente
- `-no-system-proxies` Desabilita os proxies do sistema

### Usando .LIB ao invés de .DLL

Conforme o colega @Maniero disse [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/44347/3635), talvez usar `.lib` possa favorecer no tamanho *release* final do projeto

### Não se limite ao Qt

Existem outros "SDKs" que são *cross-platform*, um bom exemplo é o GTK+

Um rápido *test-case* (note que eu compilei em `C`, usado `GCC`, mas você pode compilar em `C++` usando o `G++`)

- **main.c**

  ```
  #include <gtk/gtk.h>

  int main (int argc, char *argv[])
  {
    GtkWidget *window;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(window), "Window");
    g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gtk_main();

    return 0;
  }
  ```

Para compilar o comando:

```
gcc -o app.exe *.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

A única DLL necessária foi a `zlib1.dll`, o resultado foi 131kb:

```
./app.exe (48kb)
./zlib1.dll (83kb)
```

Comment: Não há nenhuma dll a mais, eu testei manualmente.
Comecei sem dll alguma, a que faltava, eu copiava para a pasta da executável, até o programa executar.

Comment: Vai visualizando as dlls em "amarelo", geralmente são as que faltam (ou apresentam algum erro), se for uma dll que não está na pasta do QT, talvez seja uma dll do Mingw ou VisualStudio que seja necessária.

Comment: Não está faltando, nem sobrando dll alguma.

Comment: @GabrielSales Adicione um test-case usando o MingW, infelizmente dois fatores impedem desenvolver aplicativos com baixo peso, o primeiro é o CORE do QT que veem acompanhado e se faz obrigado (o obriga a exigência das dlls) e no meu caso (mingw) a DLL obrigatoria chamada icudt53 (ICU library).

Comment: A Qt está criando alternativas: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-index.html http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/qtwebview-index.html

Comment: @bigown Obrigado pelos links, apenas postei aquilo como um relato, para mais um dos motivos de tentarmos alternativas, porém ao ler os links não consegui ver nada referente ao qtwebkit a não ser em caso do Androide iOS, conforme o link: http://qt-project.org/wiki/New-Features-in-Qt-5.4 O QtWebkit foi considerado pronto e será substituído no futuro pelo webengine. Na ultima "mailing" que vi, não há informação para tentar suportar o MingW com o Chromium no QT. Editei a resposta, espero que tenha ficado dentro do "escopo" da questão.

Answer (score 1):

As `dlls` estão grandes pois você deve estar utilizado as de debug, que são maiores mesmo. As de release são bem menores.

Para usar linkagem estática no Qt você deve ter uma licença comercial. Do contrário, você pode quebrar a licença LGPL3 ou LGPL2 da versão aberta do Qt.

---

No Qt (acho que desde o 5.2) há uma ferramenta para copiar automaticamente todos os dlls e arquivos que um programa Qt para Windows precisa, o **windeployqt**.

Para usá-lo, abra o `cmd` e depois o arquivo `qtenv2.bat` que está dentro da pasta onde o Qt para Windows está instalado.

Depois, é só chamar o programa, informando o caminho até arquivo exe gerado pelo Qt. Exemplo:

```
 windeployqt C:/foo/bat/programa_release/programa.exe
```

Nesse exemplo, os arquivos que ele copiou estão no output:

```
Adding Qt5Svg for qsvgicon.dll
Direct dependencies: Qt5Core Qt5Widgets
All dependencies   : Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Widgets
To be deployed     : Qt5Core Qt5Gui Qt5Svg Qt5Widgets
Updating icuin53.dll.
Updating icuuc53.dll.
Updating icudt53.dll.
Updating Qt5Core.dll.
Updating Qt5Gui.dll.
Updating Qt5Svg.dll.
Updating Qt5Widgets.dll.
Updating libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll.
Updating libstdc++-6.dll.
Updating libwinpthread-1.dll.
Creating directory iconengines.
Updating qsvgicon.dll.
Creating directory imageformats.
Updating qdds.dll.
Updating qgif.dll.
Updating qicns.dll.
Updating qico.dll.
Updating qjp2.dll.
Updating qjpeg.dll.
Updating qmng.dll.
Updating qsvg.dll.
Updating qtga.dll.
Updating qtiff.dll.
Updating qwbmp.dll.
Updating qwebp.dll.
Creating directory platforms.
Updating qwindows.dll.
Creating qt_ca.qm...
Creating qt_cs.qm...
Creating qt_de.qm...
Creating qt_fi.qm...
Creating qt_hu.qm...
Creating qt_it.qm...
Creating qt_ja.qm...
Creating qt_ru.qm...
Creating qt_sk.qm...
Creating qt_uk.qm...
```

E, realmente, não é pouca coisa. São quase 50 Mb de arquivos. Sendo que o QtCore + QtGui sozinhos somam quase 10 Mb.