# Quando se inclui um arquivo de cabeçalho, o compilador inclui todas as funções no programa final ou só as funções usadas?

Tags: c, c++, header

Ou seja, o executável vai ter toda a biblioteca nele ou só as funções que eu usar vão ser incluídas pelo compilador ? Com isso, incluir muitas bibliotecas pode deixar o programa pesado (ocupando muito espaço em disco) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O cabeçalho em geral só inclui as declarações das funções para fornecer informações importante para o compilador. Desta forma, se a função não for usada, há uma chance de não ser incluída a aplicação final. Se não houver nenhuma referência para a função, no momento de [*linkar*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linker_(computing)) todo o código gerado pelo compilador com as bibliotecas utilizadas, ela não será incluída.

Mas não é tão simples assim. Na verdade se você está usando algumas funções do cabeçalho e outras não, isto pode não fazer tanta diferença. É muito provável que todas as funções declaradas no cabeçalho usado estejam definidas em um binário único que não pode ser separado. Aí não tem com escolher só algumas funções, vai tudo o que está no binário, não tem como separar. Exemplo: você usou a função `a()` que está em um binário, não usou a função `b()` que está no mesmo binário, ambas estarão presentes na sua aplicação mesmo que você só tenha usado uma delas. Mas vamos dizer que no mesmo cabeçalho existe uma função `c()` mas ela não está no mesmo binário. Se ela não foi usada efetivamente, ela não será incluída. Claro que é raro você ter funções declaradas em um cabeçalho e elas estarem em binários diferentes.

Este binário é uma [unidade de compilação](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_code) que não pode ser dividida, então se você usar um membro desta unidade, todos os membros dela irão junto com sua aplicação. Este binário é chamado de [arquivo objeto](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_file) (não confundir com objetos de memória ou orientação a objeto).

Ainda é importante notar que se a função estiver [definida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136279/101) no cabeçalho, ela certamente irá na aplicação porque ela será compilada ali, na hora, pelo compilador e fará parte do seu próprio código compilado naquele momento e não será parte da biblioteca usada.

Então se incluir muitas bibliotecas, sim a aplicação ficará mais pesada. Mas se você precisa delas não importa.

Em alguns casos se precisar de uma única função que está em uma unidade de compilação grande, pode ser útil pegar a função isoladamente, se seu fonte estiver disponível e a licença permitir, e usar em separado. Mas na prática, raramente isto será importante. Em geral, as unidades de compilação não são tão grandes ou são montadas de forma a incluir suas próprias dependências mas nada extra.

Note ainda que algumas funções podem estar em uma `DLL` (ou `SO`) e não estará inclusa dentro do seu executável.

[Informação sobre bibliotecas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44269/101) que pode interessar.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).