# Qual a diferença entre declaração e definição?

Tags: funções, terminologia, independente-de-linguagem, declaração-de-variável

Essas coisas parecem ser a mesma coisa. São mesmo? E atribuição é diferente? Os termos são intercambiáveis.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Declaração

Declaração é algo que o código faz para mostrar ao compilador que um identificador existirá no código. Pode ser uma variável, função, *label*, estruturas de dados (como classes, por exemplo), entre outros. Em geral ela só ocorre uma vez no código (em algumas linguagens até é possível declarar mais de uma vez em arquivos diferentes, como identificador externo).

```
int x;
int f(int x, int y); //varia de linguagem para linguagem, mas note o ponto e vírgula
class Exemplo; //só para dizer que a classe existe
```

Algumas linguagens (dinamicamente tipadas) não exigem declaração formal da variável antes de seu uso.

Em linguagens estaticamente tipadas a declaração envolve informar o tipo da variável. Alguns linguagens podem inferir isto. A declaração é importante para reservar espaço na memória ([*stack* e/ou *heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101)) para o dado que a variável sustentará.

Algumas linguagens dizem que a declaração só ocorre como informação prévia (em geral de forma externa). Só durante a definição é que haverá reserva de memória. Faz algum sentido, mas informalmente as pessoas falam em declaração o tempo todo, e todo mundo entende que ali reserva a memória, por isso preferi colocar desta forma. Mas saiba que formalmente o termo é usado de outra forma.

## Atribuição

Atribuição só ocorre com variáveis. Ela pode ocorrer diversas vezes no código, sempre que precisar colocar um valor novo à variável. Ela pode ocorrer junto da declaração.

```
x = 10 * Sin(30) + 5; //x já estava declarada antes
//faz algo com x
x = 0; // nova atribuição
```

A primeira atribuição pode ser chamada de **inicialização**.

A maioria das linguagens inicializa a variável na declaração com um valor *default*. Algumas poucas exigem que a inicialização seja feita, ou na declaração, ou antes do primeiro uso. Há ainda algumas que permitem a variável ser usada sem uma inicialização formal, pegando o valor que estiver na memória no local reservado para ela (o que é um perigo). Existem casos que depende do contexto.

#### Objetos

Note que uma variável pode ter um valor próprio que é uma referência para um outro objeto. Muitas linguagens fazem isto de forma transparente, ou pelo menos de forma automática durante a inicialização da variável, outras podem exigir, ou pelo menos permitir que estas operações sejam independentes. Então a criação do objeto referenciado é feito manualmente pelo programador, atribuindo a referência à variável.

O objeto em si também precisa ser inicializado e cada linguagem tem um critério para fazê-lo de forma automática ou não.

Algumas linguagens só deixam o código manipular diretamente o valor do objeto e não da variável (no caso de variáveis com referências).

## Definição

#### Variável

Embora não conheça nada formal dizendo isto, eu considero que uma **atribuição** feita durante a **declaração** seja uma **definição** de variável. Algumas pessoas preferem chamar isto de **inicialização**. Não gosto tanto do termo porque a inicialização pode ser considerada a primeira atribuição, que pode ocorrer após a declaração.

```
int x = 1; //declarando e atribuindo.
var x = 2; //inferiu o tipo durante a inicialização
x : int = 3; //algumas linguagens possuem sintaxe diferente, claro
x := 4; //simples, né? O : diferencia a declaração de uma atribuição
```

A inferência de tipo normalmente só ocorre durante um definição completa de variável. Algumas linguagens possuem algoritmos mais sofisticados e fazem a inferência em atribuição futura da variável (por isso dá até para fazer com parâmetros).

#### Funções e estruturas de dados

O termo definição é bastante usado com funções e estruturas de dados. Definir é colocar o código da implementação.

Muitas vezes a declaração ocorre no momento da definição. Na verdade poucas linguagens exigem que a declaração seja separada da definição. Algumas exigem em algumas circunstâncias, quando há referências circulares. Alguns compiladores trabalham em dois passos e resolvem isto por conta própria.

```
int f(int x, int y) { return x + y; } //não tem ; no fim, mas está declarando também
class Exemplo { ... //membros aqui } //algumas linguagens exigem o ; final, outras não
Exemplo::f(int x, int y) { return x + y; } //algumas linguagens definem as funções fora
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Portugol/Variables.ptg).

Há uma controvérsia aí. Algumas pessoas consideram que mesmo quando se coloca os membros dentro da estrutura de dados, ainda é uma declaração. Então neste caso não existe definição de estruturas de dados. Pode-se definir variáveis ou objetos que vão usá-la como base, mas ela em si só é declarada. Acho esquisito porque a estrutura pode ter funções definidas. Sei lá, talvez dependa um pouco de acordo com a linguagem.

Alguns dizem que definição só ocorre depois de ter uma declaração prévia. Acho confuso. Uma coisa muda de nome baseado em algo que você nem sabe se existe?

## Instanciação

Este é um conceito um pouco diferente, mas é útil entender também. Conforme comentários, pode haver confusão com isto.

Instanciar um objeto é colocar um valor em algum lugar da memória. Este dado terá um formato específico. Mesmo linguagens dinâmicas precisam ter um formato para o dado instanciado.

A instanciação gera objetos. Onde será guardado depende do que se deseja. Pode ser na própria posição da variável (tipos por valor) ou ali vai um ponteiro e o objeto é colocado em outra área (tipos por referência). Veja mais em [Alocação de memória em C# - Tipos valor e tipos referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101) e [Qual a diferença entre Struct e Class?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16181/101) - é C#, mas dá uma ideia que vale em maior ou menor grau em outras linguagens.

Uma variável só pode ter uma instância de um tipo de cada vez. Mas é possível trocar a instância usada na variável sempre que quiser. Isto ocorre com uma atribuição. Aqui pode ser útil saber [O que "imutável" realmente significa?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/15510/101).

Instâncias não precisam estar vinculadas à variáveis, elas podem ser usadas intermediariamente e serem descartadas sem armazenamento (exceto o temporário), são bem efêmeras.

## Conclusão

Algumas linguagens podem usar os termos de forma diferente de acordo com sua especificação.

Pode parecer bobagem, mas os termos são importantes para a boa comunicação entre os programadores. As próprias respostas aqui podem falar sobre isto e se o programador não souber exatamente o que significa aquilo pode ficar um pouco confuso.

Eles costumam ser usados intercambiavelmente, mas pode gerar confusão. O melhor é usar de forma precisa, a não ser quando a precisão não traz benefício algum. Mas não menospreze os benefícios da comunicação correta.

Comment: Se entendi certo, a declaração seria em tempo de desenvolvimento(escrita do código na IDE) e a definição na compilação/execução, ou seja a **declaração** é receita com os ingredientes e a **definição** o modo de preparo e a forma como os ingredientes são combinados(alocação de mémoria) e 'aplicados', isso? Os termos parecem sinônimos dâ até um fritada na cérebro :D

Comment: @rray Eu criei esse parzinho pq há muito confusão sobre o assunto. Tentei mostrar que há diferenças entre os termos, mesmo que achem que é tudo igual. Ambos ocorrem juntos. Tudo isto está escrito no código. Estou falando sobre código, não sobre execução. Mesmo a alocação de memória, estou falando do código que manda fazer isto e não a alocação em si. Se está falando da definição da classe, acho que é a receita c/ ingredientes e modo de preparo. A declaração da variável é "vou fazer a receita tal nessa panela". A atribuição é jogar todos ingredientes na panela. A definição é fazer ambos juntos.

Comment: *"Instanciação"* seria uma forma de definição então?

Comment: @diegofm acho que pode ser usado com atribuição em certas circunstâncias. Você pode trocar a instância da variável com uma simples atribuição, não precisa ser na definição da variável (é comum que seja). Instanciar é criar o valor na memória. Note que é possível instanciar sem atribuir para alguma variável, então é outra coisa. Talvez seja até o caso de eu colocar isto na resposta. Vou pensar um pouco sobre.