# error: initializer element is not constant

Tags: c, c++, char, variáveis-globais, inicialização

Estou tentando declarar esse *buffer* em global e ao compilar apresenta o seguinte erro

> error: initializer element is not constant

```
char    *ls_buffer_PPouAUT =    malloc(5120*sizeof(char));
```

Como posso resolvê-lo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Coloque a variável dentro de uma função.

Não use nada global, é desnecessário em quase todos os casos. Nos casos que pode ser útil precisa saber bem o que está fazendo, entender todas implicações, provavelmente está usando isso inadvertidamente.

Claro, ainda é possível [declarar a variável global e inicializá-la](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136279/101) dentro da função, idealmente logo no começo da `main()` para não ficar com estado inválido. Mas evite, é melhor. Crie uma variável local e vai passando como argumento para outras funções ou armazene em uma estrutura que faça sentido.

Variáveis globais são inicializadas durante a compilação. Não pode executar a função `malloc()` nesse momento, durante a compilação só pode ter valores constantes, assim eles podem ser colocados dentro do executável gerado.

Como esse valor só pode ser conhecido durante a execução, precisa constar em um ponto dentro do fluxo de execução da aplicação. Só as funções possuem fluxo de execução.

É garantido que `sizeof char` seja 1, então não tem porque usar isso.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: obrigado, vou tentar fazer isso, inicializar dentro da função

Comment: O `*sizeof(char)` é completamente desnecessário.

Answer (score 0):

Usando como referencia  o livro do  Stephen G. Kochan (*Programming in C*) onde é citado

> É possível executar uma função que retorna um valor em tempo de
> compilação e usar o resultado como inicializador de uma variável
> global. Essa técnica pode ser útil em algumas situações, mas é um
> pouco obscura e não é frequentemente usada.

Essa  "**obscuridade**" dita pelo Kochan  refere se o fato de que essa abordagem  de usar funções de retorno de valores em tempo de compilação para inicializar variáveis globais "*pode não ser muito conhecida*".

Por tanto, onde esta foi escrito "*,durante a compilação só pode ter valores constantes...*" complementando,  executar um método que retorna um valor em tempo de compilação e utilizar como inicializador de uma variável global,poderia ser uma solução.

Então qualquer atribuição do valor ao ponteiro global fora de uma função dara erro
porque essa declaração é a inicialização  de uma variável global  que só pode ser feitas com valores constantes em tempo de compilação, fazendo com que o compilador não vai determinar o valor constante em tempo de compilação

Segui um exemplo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *ls_buffer_PPouAUT;


//A atribuição do valor ao ponteiro global fora de uma função dará erro
void aloca() {

    ls_buffer_PPouAUT = malloc(sizeof(int));
    if (ls_buffer_PPouAUT == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }
    // Atribui um valor ao ponteiro global
    *ls_buffer_PPouAUT = 13;
}

int main() {
    aloca();

    printf("global: %d ", *ls_buffer_PPouAUT);
    free(ls_buffer_PPouAUT);
    return 0;
}
```

Agora nesse caso a variável `ls_buffer_PPouAUT` é inicializada  e determinada em tempo de execução e o compilador não poderá determinar o valor da constante em tempo de compilação resultando em  `initializer element is not constant`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ls_buffer_PPouAUT = rand();

int main() {
    printf("Valor da variável global: %d\n", ls_buffer_PPouAUT);
    return 0;
}
```