# Como faço para comparar duas Strings em c

Tags: c

Basicamente o que quero fazer. É receber na linha de comandos uma String.Só que à String introduzida, têm que estar na base binária, por isso que faço um if para verificar se é binário ou não.  O meu problema está no if , porque independentemente do valor que introduza. Sempre entra no if.  - Agradeço pela vossa ajuda!

```
int main(){

     char binario [50][100]={"0000","0001","0010","0011","0100","0101","0110","0111","1000","1001","1010","1011","1100","1101","1110","1111"};

     char nome [50][100];

     int contador=0;

      printf("Insira um valor");
      scanf("%s",nome[0]);

    while(nome[contador]!='\0'){



            if (nome[0] != binario[contador])
            {
                printf("Base inicial invalida");
                break;
            }

            contador++;
     } 

     return 0;

}
```

Comment: Reverti sua edição, pois você mudou o problema da pergunta, invalidando as respostas dadas. Se tem nova dúvida, pesquise no site para ver se encontra problema similar, caso não encontre, faça uma nova pergunta com o código atualizado, descrevendo o problema exato (mas tenha a certeza de ter resolvido este passo aqui antes). Sugiro uma lida em [Ask] para algumas orientações que podem ajudar na formulação de uma nova pergunta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observe essa expressão:

```
if (nome[0] != binario[contador])
```

O resultado disso vai ser a comparação entre **o endereço de dois ponteiros de memória**. Esses dois endereços nunca serão iguais, e portanto, ele sempre vai entrar no `if`.

O que você vai querer é usar a função `strcmp`:

```
if (strcmp(nome[0], binario[contador]) != 0)
```

Entretanto, gostaria de frisar que o seu programa tem outros problemas que me levantam as seguintes dúvidas:

- Por que declarar 50 nomes se você só precisa de 1?
- Por que fazer conversão de decimal para binário usando strings, valores tabelados e tentativa-e-erro ao invés de fazer o cálculo de divisões sucessivas para isso?

Comment: Sou iniciante em **C**, tinha copiado o vector de String do binário, depois alterei os nomes e esqueci de mudar os valores.

Comment: ** Fiz da forma como sugeriram mas continua há entrar no if **

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a função [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/), declarada no arquivo de cabeçalho (ou arquivo *header*) `string.h`. Note que a função `strcmp` compara o conteúdo das *strings* e não seu tamanho.

**Exemplo:**

```
strcmp(string1,string2);
```

A função te retornará até três valores. São eles:

- **= 0:** as duas *strings* são idênticas.
- **> 0:** o primeiro caractere diferente tem um valor maior que na outra *string*.
- **< 0:** o primeiro caractere diferente tem um valor menor que na outra *string*.

Veja o [exemplo](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char key[] = "maçã";
  char buffer[80];
  do {
     printf ("Adivinhe minha fruta favorita? ");
     fflush (stdout);
     scanf ("%79s",buffer);
  } while (strcmp (key,buffer) != 0);
  puts ("Resposta correta!");
  return 0;
}
```

Saída:

> ```
> Adivinhe minha fruta favorita? laranja
> Adivinhe minha fruta favorita? maçã
> Resposta correta!
> ```

Leia [aqui](https://tentandoblogar.wordpress.com/2009/03/15/comparando-palavras-em-c-a-funcao-strcmp/) e [aqui também](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8004237/how-do-i-properly-compare-strings-in-c) <sub>em inglês</sub>.

Comment: A função "strcmp" é **declarada** no arquivo de cabeçalho (ou arquivo header) "string.h". Este arquivo não é uma "biblioteca", é simplesmente um arquivo fonte contendo declarações. E em C e C++ "declaração" e "definição" são termos técnicos, com significados diferentes.

Comment: Opa! Obrigado, pelo jeito vamos aprendendo até respondendo. E desculpe pelo erro, já editei a resposta.

Comment: Deixo também [este link](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136279/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-declara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o) para complementar seu comentário.