# Acessar variavel local fora de um if

Tags: variáveis, if, lua, escopo-de-variáveis

Como criar/modificar uma variável dentro de um `if` e poder acessá-la sem ter que *setá-la* em modo global/escopo. Estou trabalhando em um arquivo Lua semelhante a este esquema:

```
    if verificacao then
        local variavelDoArquivo = 123
    end

    -- preciso acessar a variável que foi criada pelo if verificação fora do if mas no mesmo arquivo. Ex:
print(variavelDoArquivo)
```

Veja [funcionando no ideone](http://ideone.com/bJdvjy) e [no CodingGround](https://goo.gl/U6GBZt).

Nesta situação retornou em branco no console, mas em alguns casos retornou nil em outras situações. Como eu posso criar/*setar* uma variável dentro do `if` e poder acessar ela externamente sem ter de criar um escopo?

Não sei se está fazendo o que deseja, mas é a solução. Eu acho que inicializar a variável já na declaração e só mudar seu valor dentro do `if` seria melhor, mas depende do resultado que espera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare-a fora do `if` e atribua dentro:

```
local variavelDoArquivo
if true then
    variavelDoArquivo = 123
end
print(variavelDoArquivo)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Lua/LocalVar.lua).

Leia mais sobre [Qual a diferença entre declaração e definição?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136279/101) e [Qual a diferença entre escopo e tempo de vida?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101).