# too many arguments to function 'endereco* encontra()'

Tags: c, c++, funções

Estou tentando compilar este código no DevC++ porém continua dando este erro

> [Error] too many arguments to function 'endereco* encontra()'

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct endereco 
{
    char nome[30];
    char rua[40];
    char cidade[20];
    char estado[3];
    char cep[10];
    struct endereco *proximo;  
/*ponteiro para a próxima entrada */
    struct endereco *anterior; 
/*ponteiro para registro anterior */
} lista;

struct endereco *primeiro; 
/*ponteiro para a primeiro entrada da lista*/
struct endereco *ultimo;   
/*ponteiro para a   ultimo entrada da lista*/ 

struct endereco *encontra(char *);

void entra(void);
void procura(void);
void salva(void);
void carrega(void);
void listar(void);
void apaga(struct endereco **, struct endereco **);
void armazena(struct endereco *i,struct endereco **inicio, 
                                 struct endereco **ultimo);
void entrada(char *,char *,int);
void exibe(struct endereco *);
int seleciona_menu(void);

int main(void)
{
    /*inicializa os ponteiros de topo e fundo*/
    primeiro = NULL;
    ultimo   = NULL;

    while(1) 
    {
        switch(seleciona_menu()) 
        {
            case 1: entra();
                break;
            case 2: apaga(&primeiro, &ultimo);
                break;
            case 3: listar();
                break;
            case 4: procura(); /*encontra uma rua*/
                break;
            case 5: salva(); /* grava a lista no disco*/
                break;
            case 6: carrega(); /*lê do disco*/
                break;
            case 7: exit(0);
        }
    }
}

/* Seleciona uma operação */

int seleciona_menu(void)
{
    char s[80];
    int c;
    puts("1 : Inserir um nome");
    puts("2 : Apagar um nome");
    puts("3 : Listar o arquivo");
    puts("4 : Pesquisar");
    puts("5 : Salvar o arquivo");
    puts("6 : Carregar o arquivo");
    puts("7 : Sair");
    do 
    {
        printf("\nEntre com sua escolha: ");
        gets(s);
        c = atoi(s);
    }while(c<0 || c>7);
    return c;
}
/* Insere nomes e endereços */
void entra(void)
{
    struct endereco *info;
    while(1)
    {
        info = (struct endereco *)malloc(sizeof(lista));
        if(!info)
        {
            printf("\nSem memória");
            return;
        }
        entrada("Entre o nome: ",info->nome,30);
        if(!info->nome[0]) break; /*Não efetua a inserção */
        entrada("Entre a rua: ",info->rua,40);      
        entrada("Entre a cidade: ",info->cidade,20);
        entrada("Entre a estado: ",info->estado,3);
        entrada("Entre a cep: ",info->cep,10);
        armazena(info,&primeiro,&ultimo);
    } /*laço de entrada*/
}
/* Esta função lê ua string de comprimento máximo cont e evita que a 
string seja ultrapassada. Ela também apresenta uma menssagem */

void entrada(char *menssagem,char *s,int cont)
{
    char p[255];
    //int tamanho;
    do
    {
        printf(menssagem);
        gets(p);
        //tamanho = strlen(p);
        if(strlen(p) > (size_t)cont) printf("\nMuito longo\n");
    }while(strlen(p) > (size_t)cont);
    strcpy(s,p);
}
/*Cria uma lista duplamente encadeada ordenada*/
void armazena(struct endereco *i,         /*novo elemento*/
              struct endereco **primeiro, /*primeiro elemento da lista*/
              struct endereco **ultimo)   /*último   elemento da lista*/
{
    struct endereco *velho, *p;
    if(ultimo == NULL) /*primeiro elemento da lista*/
    {
        i->proximo  =  NULL;
        i->anterior = NULL;
        *ultimo     = i;
        *primeiro   = i;
        return;
    }
    p = *primeiro; /* começa no topo da lista*/
    velho = NULL;
    while(p)
    {
        if(strcpy(p->nome,i->nome)<0)
        {
            velho = p;
            p = p->proximo;
        }
        else 
        {
            if(p->anterior)
            {
                p->anterior->proximo = i;
                i->proximo = p;
                i->anterior = p->anterior;
                p->anterior = i;
                return;
            }
            i->proximo = p; /*novo primeiro elemento*/ 
            i->anterior = NULL;
            p->anterior = i;
            *primeiro = i;
            return;
        }
    }
    velho->proximo = i; /*coloca no final*/
    i->proximo = NULL;
    i->anterior = velho;
    *ultimo = i;
}

/* Remove um elementi da lista */
void apaga(struct endereco **primeiro,struct endereco **ultimo)
{
    struct endereco *info;
    struct endereco *encontra();
    char s[80];
    printf("Entre o nome: ");
    gets(s);
    info = encontra(s);

    if(info)
    {
        if(*primeiro == info)
        {
            *primeiro = info->proximo;
            if(*primeiro) 
                (*primeiro)->anterior = NULL;
            else
                *ultimo = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            info->anterior->proximo = info->proximo;
            if(info != *ultimo)
                info->proximo->anterior = info->anterior;
            else
                *ultimo = info->anterior;
        }
        free(info); /*devole memoria para o sistema*/
    }
}
/*Encontra um endereço */
struct endereco *encontra(char *nome)
{
    struct endereco *info;
    info = primeiro;
    while(info)
    {
        if(!strcmp(nome, info->nome) )return info;
        info = info->proximo; /*obtém novo endereço*/
    }
    printf("Nome não encontrado\n");
    return NULL; /*não encontrou*/
}
/*Mostra a lista completa*/
void listar(void)
{
    struct endereco *info;
    info = primeiro;
    while(info)
    {
        exibe(info);
        info = info->proximo; /*obtém próximo endereço*/
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
void exibe(struct endereco *info)
{
    printf("%s\n",info->nome);
    printf("%s\n",info->rua);
    printf("%s\n",info->cidade);
    printf("%s\n",info->estado);
    printf("%s\n",info->cep);
    printf("\n\n");
}
/*Procura por um nome na lista*/
void procura(void)
{
    char nome[40];
    struct endereco *info;
    struct endereco *encontra();
    puts("Entre com o nome a procurar: ");
    gets(nome);
    info = encontra(nome);
    if(!info)
        printf("Não encontrou\n");
    else
        exibe(info);
}
/*Salva o arquivo em disco. */
void salva(void)
{
    struct endereco *info;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("lista.txt","wb");
    if(!fp)
    {
        puts("Arquivo nao pôde ser aberto");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("\nSalvando arquivo...\n");
    info = primeiro;
    while(info)
    {
        fwrite(info,sizeof(struct endereco),1,fp);
        info = info->proximo; /*obtém próximo endereço*/
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
/*Carrega o arquivo de endereço */
void carrega()
{
    struct endereco *info;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("lista.txt","rb");
    if(!fp)
    {
        puts("Arquivo nao pôde ser aberto");
        exit(1);
    }
    /*libera qualquer memória previamente alocada*/
    while(primeiro)
    {
        info = primeiro->proximo;
        free(info);
        primeiro = info;
    }
    /*reinicializa os ponteiros de início e fim*/
    primeiro = NULL;
    ultimo   = NULL;
    printf("\nCarregando arquivo...\n");
    while(!feof(fp))
    {
        info = (struct endereco *)malloc(sizeof(struct endereco));
        if(!info)
        {
            printf("sem memória");
            return;
        }
        if(1 != fread(info,sizeof(struct endereco),1,fp)) break;
        armazena(info, &primeiro,&ultimo);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

[image: [Error] too many arguments to function 'endereco* encontra()']
[image: [Error] too many arguments to function 'endereco* encontra()']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vamos pegar esse início de função:

```
void apaga(struct endereco **primeiro, struct endereco **ultimo) {
    struct endereco *info;
    struct endereco *encontra(); // =============> declaração aqui
    char s[80];
    printf("Entre o nome: ");
    gets(s);
    info = encontra(s);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/NumberParameters.c).

Você declara uma função dentro dessa função. [Só declara, não define](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136279/101). Isso já é esquisito, está no caminho para dar algo errado. Na declaração não há parâmetros, os parênteses estão vazios. Aí na última linha usa a função passando um argumento. Não vai funcionar.

> Ah, mas eu declarei essa função com um parâmetro em outro lugar

A prioridade é da que está mais perto. Nem sei porque declarou essa função aí. Eu só tiraria isso. Talvez tenha outros erros desse tipo.

Não consigo fazer afirmações mais precisas porque o código é bem confuso.

`gets()` não deve ser usando nem em C, quanto mais em C++. Só para citar um problema no código. Na verdade esse código não tem nada de C++.

Dev C++ é um IDE bem problemático e deveria ser abandonado. Não sei porque tanta gente usa algo tão ruim.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, qual IDE seria melhor recomendada ?

Comment: Eu não recomendo nada. Existe o Visual Studio, Code::Blocks, Eclipe, NetBeans, CLion, só para citar alguns.