# Qual a diferença em instanciar, inicializar e declarar uma variável?

Tags: variáveis, terminologia, declaração-de-variável, independente-de-linguagem, inicialização

Muitos artigos na internet se referem à esses verbos, independente da linguagem de programação. Porém algumas vezes todos eles são confundidos ou permutados, que gera muito confusão.

O que significa "instanciar", "inicializar" e "declarar" uma variável?

Comment: Relacionada: [Qual a diferença entre declaração e definição?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136279/28595)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A definição de "declarar" pode ver em [Qual a diferença entre declaração e definição?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136279/28595).

"Inicializar" podemos dizer que que é sinônimo de atribuir um primeiro valor, não necessariamente na declaração.

"Instanciar" é criar um objeto, é montar na memória um valor para este objeto.

[Objeto nada tem a ver com programação orientada a objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/205482/101), objetos existem em todos [paradigmas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101).

Você pode instanciar um objeto e:

- colocar um valor durante a declaração da variável
- inicializar uma variável em outro ponto após a declaração
- atribuir a uma variável previamente inicializada, trocando assim seu valor
- passar como argumento para um [parâmetro](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101)
- não armazenar em [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101).

Um elemento de um *array*, coleção ou um membro de outro objeto também é uma variável.

Quando você faz

```
var x = 1;
```

Está declarando uma variável, inicializando ela com um valor instanciado. Esse valor é uma instância do tipo `number` em JS, ou `int` em C# ou Java. Um tipo `string` poderia ser:

```
var a = "teste";
```

Algumas instanciações não possuem literais na linguagem e precisam usar construtores:

```
var i = new Classe(10, "texto");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Object/Instance.js).

A variável `i` armazenará uma instância (um objeto) do tipo `Classe` (na verdade uma referência para esta instância).

Alguns objetos são [por valor outros por referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/14490/101), isso muda o [tempo de vida](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) e possivelmente o [local da memória que será armazenado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101).

Answer (score 1):

Sendo bem simples e objetivo à sua pergunta...

> O que significa "instanciar", "inicializar" e "declarar" uma variável?

**Instanciar** se refere a uma classe. Então você vai instanciar em uma variável a classe.

```
var pessoa = new Pessoa()
```

**Inicializar** nada mais é que você atribuir um valor para uma variável. Por exemplo, você não pode em certos momentos trabalhar com atributos de um objeto se você não dizer antes que essa variável é um objeto. No caso, inicializamos a variável antes de usa-la. Apenas fazemos com que ela exista antes de mais nada.

```
var variavel = null;
var pessoa_object = {};
```

**Declarar** é parecido com inicializar, porém você não precisa necessariamente atribuir um valor.

```
int idade;
```

Comment: Sinto muito, mas creio que sua definição de "declarar" esteja errada. Eu posso declarar um objeto e deixar ele em um estado não inicializado, inclusive isso é um erro de compilação no Java, enquanto que no JS vai dar um erro de objeto indefinido

Comment: Editei. Realmente, não preciso necessariamente atribuir um valor quando declaro uma variável, diferente de inicializar. Obrigado