# Como colocar uma palavra inteira dentro de um char?

Tags: c

Como    faço para   colocar   uma palavra com letras    e    números    dentro    de    um     char?    Por exemplo    colocar    nele    a    placa    de    um  carro    ABC-1234.

```
char a = ABC1234;
char b = DFG0000;   

printf("1ª placa %s\n",a);  
printf("2ª placa %s\n",b);
```

Dá erro no código. Como eu procedo?

Comment: Para podermos te ajudar, [forneça um código Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: blz vou alterar a pergunta

Comment: Pelo que você está dizendo, parece ser o caso de [marcar uma resposta como aceita](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/). Aqui não escrevemos "resolvido" na questão. Se tem uma resposta que realmente te ajudou, marque-a como aceita. Se chegou sozinho à solução, poste a solução como resposta. Assim o conteúdo fica mais organizado e fácil de ser encontrado futuramente por outras pessoas com problemas parecidos.

Answer (score 4):

Conhece a diferença entre caracter e string? O tipo `char` é um caracter, portanto aceita apenas informação escalar. Você quer uma informação vetorial, deveria usar uma string para esse caso. No caso, em C, isso seria algo como `char placa_a[] = "ABC0123";`

Aproveitando também, o parâmetro `%s` do `printf` não espera receber uma variável escalar, mas um ponteiro de caracteres. Você obterá resultados estranhos caso sua aplicação não feche grosseiramente com uma falha de segmentação para o uso que você deu.

---

Outro ponto: strings constantes em C se declaram entre aspas. Portanto, se eu quiser inicializar a variável chamada `placa_a` com uma palavra, eu precisa fazer:

```
placa_a = "ABC1234";
```

Essa inicialização pode ser feita para a definição de `placa_a` como um ponteiro como também como sendo um vetor.

Então, as opções seriam:

```
// inicializando um vetor
char placa_a_vetor[] = "ABC0123";
// inicializando o ponteiro junto da declaração 
char *placa_a_ptr = "ABC0123";

// primeiro declarando, depois inicializando
char *placa_a_ptr_delayed;
placa_a_ptr_delayed = "ABC0123";
```

---

Leitura recomendada:

- [Na prática, qual a utilidade dos ponteiros em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/244828/64969)
- [Comentário distinguindo ponteiro e referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/244828/na-pr%c3%a1tica-qual-a-utilidade-dos-ponteiros-em-c/244834#comment502630_244834)
- [Qual a diferença em instanciar, inicializar e declarar uma variável?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182990/64969)

Comment: muito obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Cara basicamente você não pode fazer isso com um `char` "normal", uma variável deste tipo é feita para armazenar apenas um caractere, logo para você poder armazenar uma cadeia de caracteres (string) em uma variável é necessário que você utilize uma string, esta que seria equivalente a um vetor (array) do tipo `char` em C.

Para declarar uma string é muito fácil, você primeiro necessita ter em mente quantas letras a palavra que você deseja armazenar tem, após isso é só você declarar a variável igual você declararia um vetor, só que utilizando `char` é claro, é muito importante ressaltar que no final de toda as string vai o caracterizar '\0', este simboliza que sua string chegou ao final, logo quando for fazer a contagem de quantas letras a palavra que deseja armazenar tem, para poder criar a string, lembre-se de sempre somar um a ais no resultado final, este que será reservado ao '\0'.

ex:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char strNumPlaca[50] = "ABC - 03257";

    printf("%s", strNumPlaca); /*   use %s ao invés de %c, pois isso simboliza
                                    que você esta utilizando uma string.    */

    return 0;
}
```

Para ajudar na sua compreensão aqui esta um link:
http://linguagemc.com.br/string-em-c-vetor-de-caracteres/

Comment: Você não precisaria declarar o tamanho da string `strNumPlaca` para esse caso em específico. O compilador C fará o ajuste automaticamente para você, de modo que ela seja de tamanho 11 (3 letras, 4 números, 3 caracteres de formatação e o terminador nulo). Claro, se for a ideia reutilizar essa string em um contexto que se necessite 49 caracteres e o terminador faz sentido declarar o tamanho...

Comment: ss, mas eu achei que iria ficar muita coisa para explicar para ele, então de inicio isso era suficiente

Answer (score 0):

Sobre sua questão tem 2 pontos a entender, vamos lá.
1º Para a declaração de um char com alguns caracteres, sejam eles especiais, números, o que você achar melhor, é necessário o uso de chaves [] e um número, ou variável (se forem N valores, e se o valor de N já tiver sido escolhido), varia de acordo com a necessidade, e ainda precisa colocar seus caracteres dentro de aspas duplas, assim char palavra[3] = "sim";.
2º Se você quer concatenar uma string, utiliza-se a função strcat, que funciona com a biblioteca string.h.
Espero ter ajudado