# Valores de Impresso Incorretos

Tags: c, loop

Não to sabendo onde estou errando e está imprimindo os valores incorretos da media.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (){
int i, num, soma, maior, menor;
float media;

printf ("Informe 10 valores:\n");
for (i=1; i<=10; i++){
    scanf ("%d", &num);
    if (i==0){
        maior=num;
        menor=num;
    }
    else{
        if (num > maior){
            maior=num;
        }
        if (num < menor){
            menor=num;
        }
}
soma = soma + num;
media = soma / 10;
}
printf ("Media: %.2f", media);
printf ("\nMaior: %d", maior);
printf ("\nMenor: %d", menor);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue abaixo o código com algumas correções.

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main (){
    int i, num, soma, maior, menor;
    float media;

    printf ("Informe 10 valores:\n");
    soma=0;//Faltava inicializar a variável soma, estava com valor "lixo" da memória
    for (i=0; i<10; i++)//inicializei em 0, com i=1 ele não estava tratando todos os valores de num
    {
        scanf ("%d", &num);
        if (i==0){
            maior=num;
            menor=num;
        }
        else{
            if (num > maior){
                maior=num;
            }
            if (num < menor){
                menor=num;
            }
    }
    soma = soma + num;//Somatório de todos os 10 valores
    }
    media = soma / 10.0;//Soma dividido por 10.0, divisão de int por float resulta em float
    printf ("Media: %.2f", media);
    printf ("\nMaior: %d", maior);
    printf ("\nMenor: %d", menor);
    }
```

Fiz o teste com valores de 1 até 10 e obtive a seguinte saida:

```
    Media: 5.50
    Maior: 10
    Menor: 1
```

Comment: Funcionou direitinho obrigado ♥

Comment: Comentários feitos.

Answer (score 4):

Tem diversos erros, provavelmente uma mistura de convenções sem que você tenha percebido:

1. `i` nunca é zero, então nunca inicia os valores de `menor` nem de `maior`
2. O valor de `soma` não é inicializado, portanto carrega lixo de memória
3. O cálculo de `media` está sendo feito com aritmética inteira
4. Você não precisa calcular a média a cada iteração

### Resolvendo os problemas

O primeiro é iterar começando em 0 e indo até 10 no intervalo aberto. Ou seja:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) ...
```

Simplesmente declarar a variável `soma` já [inicializada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182990/64969) resolve o problema:

```
int i, num, soma = 0, maior, menor;
```

Retirar o cálculo de média do meio da iteração, mas mantendo o cálculo de `soma` resolve o item 4.

Ao terminar a iteração, fazer a divisão por 10 como ponto flutuante resolve o item 3:

```
media = soma / 10.0f
```

Comment: Se meu i iniciar no 0 o numero impresso no menor fica incorreto.

Comment: Então tem mais coisa... pera

Comment: Não enxergo nada ainda que possa estar errado além do que já apontei, vou precisar por no ideone. Cc @GustavoCarvalho

Comment: Antes eu tava tendo problemas porque não estava mostrando os valores em maior e menor estavam saindo como 0 porem a media saia certa, ai vi que eles tavam no float ai coloquei eles como int so que agora a media sai errada e os valores e maior e menor sai correto.

Comment: Faltou inicializar `soma`, atualizando a resposta

Comment: como assim inicializar a soma?