# System.NullReferenceException em um atributo do tipo StringBuilder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, nullpointerexception

Qual o motivo do erro ocorrer? Como corrigir?

#### Model:

```
public class modelExemplo
{
        public StringBuilder listNewsletter { get; set; }

}
```

#### Controller:

```
public ActionResult funcaodeteste()
{
    modelExemplo obj = new modelExemplo();
    obj.listNewsletter.AppendLine("teste1");
    obj.listNewsletter.AppendLine("teste2");    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O objeto da propriedade precisa ser inicializado:

```
public StringBuilder listNewsletter { get; set; } = new StringBuilder();
```

Se usar uma versão antiga do C# precisa fazer isto em um construtor, exemplo básico:

```
public modelExemplo() {
    listNewsletter = new StringBuilder();
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Exception/NullReferenceException.cs).

[Declarar uma variável de um tipo é diferente de instanciar um objeto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/182990/101) para ele. Sem um objeto existente qualquer operação nele falhará.

Comment: Maravilha, muito obrigado pela resposta, ficou extremamente clara e objetiva e o melhor, funcionou rs.

Answer (score 3):

Isso acontece, porque `StringBuilder` é uma classe **que não é estatica**, ou seja, *precisa ser instanciada* (inicializada). Faça isso no seu construtor.

```
public class modelExemplo
{
        public modelExemplo(){
            listNewsletter = new StringBuilder();
        }

        public StringBuilder listNewsletter { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`listNewsletter` está null, portanto `listNewsletter.AppendLine` irá disparar uma `NullReferenceException`

Você pode corrigir isso inicializando `listNewsletter` no construtor da sua classe:

```
public class modelExemplo
{
    public StringBuilder listNewsletter { get; set; }

    public modelExemplo(){
        listNewsletter = new StringBuilder();
    }

}
```

Sugiro que dê uma lida [neste excelente tópico.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/90363/o-que-realmente-significa-null)

Comment: Irei olhar Artur, muito obrigado.