# Ajuda com lógica - Portugol Studio

Tags: lógica, portugol

bom dia!
Estou tentando aprender a programar, comecei por lógica + portugol.
Ao tentar realizar um exercicio da condição para, aconteceu o seguinte erro no portugol studio:

"Existem trechos de código onde a variável nomeMenor pode não ter sido iniciada"

```
   programa
{
    funcao inicio()
    {
        
        cadeia nome, nomeMaior, nomeMenor
        inteiro idade, cont
        inteiro idadeMaior = 0
        inteiro idadeMenor = 999
        real soma = 0.0
        real media = 0.0
        
        para (cont = 0; cont < 10; cont++) {
            escreva("Nome: ")
            leia(nome)

            escreva("Idade: ")
            leia(idade)

            se (idade < idadeMenor) {
                idadeMenor = idade
                nomeMenor = nome
            }

            se (idade > idadeMaior) {
                idadeMaior = idade
                nomeMaior = nome
            }

            soma = soma + idade
        }

        media = soma / 10
        escreva("A média de idades é: ", media, "\n")
        escreva(nomeMenor , " tem a menor idade que é: ", idadeMenor , " anos.\n")
        escreva(nomeMaior , " tem a maior idade que é: ", idadeMaior , " anos.\n")
    }
}
```

Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Anderson, você não consegue utilizar uma variável que não foi inicializada, porque espera-se que a variável tenha um valor para ser utilizada, e como não foi inicializada, não contém valor algum. Como você só definia um valor para a variável nomeMenor dentro do para mas utilizava a variável fora do para, era preciso garantir que a variável fosse inicializada

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi a questão!
Devido as novas versões do Portugol Studio, o mesmo esta pedindo que seja atribuído valores as variáveis.

Por exemplo:

```
cadeia nome = ""
inteiro idade = 0
real preco = 0.0
```

Comment: Anderson, você não consegue utilizar uma variável que não foi [inicializada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/182997/165800), porque espera-se que a variável tenha um valor para ser utilizada, e como não foi inicializada, não contém valor algum. Como você só definia um valor para a variável `nomeMenor` dentro do `para` mas utilizava a variável fora do `para`, era preciso garantir que a variável fosse inicializada antes do `para`.

Comment: É uma "precaução", já que deve-se considerar a possibilidade de o seu código nunca executar o que está dentro do `para`, mantendo a variável `nomeMenor` sem valor algum. ;)