# Por que existem dois const na declaração de variável?

Tags: c, c++, ponteiro, declaração-de-variável, const

Eu posso fazer isto:

```
const int* const objeto = &x;
```

Por que existem dois `const`? Qual a função de cada um?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Eles determinam a capacidade de alterar o valor de um objeto na memória. Lembre-se que tipos que usam ponteiro possuem duas partes distintas, uma é o próprio ponteiro que fica armazenado na variável, e o objeto que é apontado pelo ponteiro.

O `const` mais à esquerda impede que o valor do objeto seja trocado depois de inicializado. O `const` mais à direita impede que o ponteiro seja trocado, ou seja, que a variável aponte para outro objeto diferente e potencialmente seja um novo valor.

Fiz exemplos e comentei os códigos que não funcionariam para poder compilar.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int x1 = 1, x2 = 2, x3 = 3, x4 = 4;
    int* p1;
    p1 = &x1;
    *p1 = 10;
    const int* p2;
    p2 = &x2;
    //*p2 = 20; //tentativa de trocar o valor do objeto
    int* const p3 = &x3;
    //p3 = &x1; //tentativa de trocar o ponteiro para o objeto
    *p3 = 30;
    const int* const p4 = &x4;
    //p4 = &x2; //tentativa de trocar o valor do objeto
    //*p4 = 40; //tentativa de trocar o ponteiro para o objeto
    printf("%d %d %d %d", *p1, *p2, *p3, *p4);
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/3tLoZ3). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/qpfhizzj-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Pointer/Const.c).

É interessante entender sobre [Qual a diferença entre declaração e definição?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136279/101).