# Referenciar struct dentro de outra em C

Tags: c, struct

Preciso que exista uma referencia de `struct` dentro da outra. Mas no exemplo abaixo como a `struct TAnimal` ainda não existe, a referencia dela na `struct` jogador da erro. Como contornar essa situação?

```
 typedef struct jogador{
    char nome[50];
    TAnimal* animal;
 }TJogador;

typedef struct animal{
    char nome[50];  
    TJogador* jogador;
}TAnimal;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando há referência cíclica tem que declarar a estrutura antes de usá-la e depois defini-la depois. Veja [Qual a diferença entre declaração e definição?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136279/101).

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct animal TAnimal;

 typedef struct jogador {
    char nome[50];
    TAnimal* animal;
 } TJogador;

struct animal {
    char nome[50];  
    TJogador* jogador;
};

int main(void) {
    TJogador jogador = { .nome = "abc" };
    TAnimal animal = { .nome = "hipopo", .jogador = &jogador };
    jogador.animal = &animal;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/y9J8Ab). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/dzcrlzpt-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/CyclicReference.c).

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou!