# Definição de Struct em C

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct

Olá, meu professor fez a seguinte definição de algumas structs para um código de uma lista em estrutura de dados, mas infelizmente não consigo compreender a definição de cada struct em si.

```
typedef struct{
    int Chave;
}TipoItem;

typedef struct TipoCelula *TipoApontador;// Maior dúvida

typedef struct TipoCelula{
    TipoItem Item;
    TipoApontador Prox;
}TipoCelula;

typedef struct TipoLista{
    TipoApontador Primeiro, Ultimo;
}TipoLista;
```

Não consegui entender principalmente a linha comentada, pois pelo que eu entendi ele definiu um ponteiro que aponta para uma struct TipoCelula que nem havia sido criada!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seu professor não *"definiu um ponteiro que aponta para uma `struct TipoCelula`"* ele **nomeou um símbolo para o tipo** `struct TipoCelula*` **usando** `typedef`.

Fique atento, [*declaração* não é a mesma coisa que *definição*!](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136279/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-declara%C3%A7%C3%A3o-e-defini%C3%A7%C3%A3o)

O `typedef` é muito útil para se dar nomes simbólicos para tipos de dados.

Para entender melhor o que acontece, vamos "remover" os `typedefs` dos seu código, ficaria algo assim:

```
struct Item
{
    int Chave;
};

struct Celula
{
    struct Item item;
    struct Celula * Prox;
};


struct Lista
{
    struct Celula * Primeiro;
    struct Celula * Ultimo;
};
```

Agora, vamos criar nomes simbólicos para cada uma das estruturas definidas utilizando `typedef`, só que de forma *separada*, reescrevendo tudo ficaria algo como:

```
typedef struct Item   TipoItem;
typedef struct Celula TipoCelula;
typedef struct Lista  TipoLista;

struct Item
{
    int Chave;
};

struct Celula
{
    TipoItem Item;
    TipoCelula * Prox;
};


struct Lista
{
    TipoCelula * Primeiro;
    TipoCelula * Ultimo;
};
```

Ponteiros para tipos também podem ser nomeados simbolicamente usando `typedef`, essa é uma das técnicas usadas pelo seu professor que você não foi capaz de entender, veja só:

```
typedef struct Item   TipoItem;
typedef struct Celula TipoCelula;
typedef struct Lista  TipoLista;

typedef struct TipoCelula* TipoApontadorCelula;


struct Item
{
    int Chave;
};

struct Celula
{
    TipoItem Item;
    TipoApontadorCelula Prox;
};


struct Lista
{
    TipoApontadorCelula Primeiro;
    TipoApontadorCelula Ultimo;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Qual o problema de usar um tipo que ainda não foi definido? Você não precisa da definição dele, basta ele existir. Não pode usar antes da definição quando o uso depende da definição, neste caso só precisa do nome.

Vamos deixar mais claro que está fazendo:

```
typedef (struct TipoCelula *) TipoApontador;
```

Então esta linha está criando um tipo novo chamado `TipoApontador`. Este tipo será um ponteiro para uma estrutura `TipoCelula`.

Quando está usando:

```
TipoApontador Prox;
```

Está fazendo na verdade:

```
struct TipoCelula *Prox;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/Pointer3.c).

Comment: Mas e nessa definição de funções, o TipoLista é uma struct de ponteiros, então o que diferencia essas duas definições de funções:
    void FLVazia(TipoLista *Lista);

    int Vazia(TipoLista Lista);

Comment: Não vi nenhuma definição de função aí. `TipoLista` é uma estrutura com dois membros, ambos são o do tipo `TipoApontador` (acho estes nomes horríveis).