# Qual é a utilidade do comando struct em c?

Tags: c, struct

Eu já aprendi como utilizar o comando em um código, mas ainda não entendi exatamente pra que ele serve. Alguém poderia me explicar, com exemplos se possível, a sua utilidade?

Comment: struct não é um comando, é um tipo de dado que serve basicamente de grosso modo para agrupar outros tipos de dados

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Definição de Struct em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/260747/defini%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-struct-em-c)

Comment: @SamuelIves foi erro meu, tava com bastante sono na hora, acabei escrevendo besteira

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O struct é utilizado basicamente para agrupar variáveis que tenham um objetivo comum e criar novos tipos de dados. Tecnicamente, a struct irá alinhar fisicamente esses dados na memória permitindo que eles sejam acessados por um ponto único de acesso. Por exemplo: Se você precisa armazenar dados de uma pessoa como 'nome', 'idade', 'genero', etc.. defina uma struct chamada 'pessoa' com os dados que precisa.

```
struct pessoa {
  char *nome;
  unsigned int idade;
  char genero[1]; // M ou F
};

// Declaração da variável p utilizando a struct pessoa
struct pessoa p;

// Definição dos valores. 
p.nome = "Joao";  
p.idade = 12;
p.genero = 'M';
```

Comment: Obgd msm, agora eu entendi, não sabia que o comando chegava a alinhar os dados na memória. Eu te daria um upvote se eu pudesse, mas sabe como é, menos de 15 pontos kkk