# 'nome_da_função': Identificador não encontrado

Tags: c, c++, funções

```
void inserePoli1(poli **topo1, int val, int expo) {
    polinomio1 *novo;
    char cmd;
    novo = new poli;
    novo->valor = val;
    novo->expoente = expo;
    if (*topo1 == NULL) {
        novo->prox = NULL;
        *topo1 = novo;
    }
    else {
        novo->prox = *topo1;
        *topo1 = novo;
    }
    cout << "Deseja inserir mais um elemento? (sim - S/não - N)" << endl;
    cin >> cmd;
    if (cmd == 's') {
        criaPoli1(val, expo, *topo1);
     }
}

void criaPoli1(int &val, int &expo, poli *topo1) {
    cout << "\nInsira o VALOR: ";
    cin >> val;
     cout << "Insira o EXPOENTE: ";
    cin >> expo;
    inserePoli1(&topo1, val, expo);
}
```

Levando em consideração que abaixo dessas duas funções a minha `main()` já possui a chamada para `criapoli1`, como posso chamar esta mesma função, sendo que colocando criapoli1 acima de `inserepoli1` resulta em erro e vice versa também retorna erro uma vez que uma chama a outra...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coloca antes só a [declaração e deixa a definição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136279/101) para depois:

```
void criaPoli1(int &val, int &expo, poli *topo1);
```

Pode até fazer:

```
void criaPoli1(int &, int &, poli *);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/Declaration.c).

Comment: Poderia exemplificar usando meu próprio codigo?

Comment: Eu poderia se tivesse colocado corretamente, mas sem nem dar para entender o que tem nele fica um pouco mais complicado.

Comment: depois que cliquei no link eu compreendi o que precisava fazer, muito obrigado!!