# Quantas vezes a variável x será criada ao final do loop? Por que?

Tags: java, variáveis, loop, declaração-de-variável

No seguinte laço, quantas vezes a variável `x` será criada ao final do *loop*? Por que?

```
for (int i = 0; < 10; i++) 
{
    double x = i + 10;
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A palavra "criada" aí é um pouco complicada. Informalmente usamos a palavra, mas criação não é bem o termo que ocorre aí nesse código. Há uma [declaração de variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136279/101) `x`, e apenas uma, portanto se quer saber quantas vezes isso ocorre é **uma**. Se quer saber quantas variáveis são criadas aí, é apenas **uma**. Se quer saber quantos espaços na memória são alocados para esta variável, é apenas **um** espaço. Para todos os efeitos só há criação de **uma variável**.

Se por [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101) entendemos o que ela realmente é, ou seja, um local de armazenamento com um nome para fácil acesso, então só há a criação de **uma** variável.

Há 10 atribuições nesta **única** variável e portanto são criados 10 **valores** (instâncias de objetos) que são sucessivamente armazenados na mesma variável, portanto, apesar dos votos positivos e aceitação, as outras respostas estão erradas e se confundiram com a ideia de variável e valor (uma delas sequer responde à pergunta).

Quando você declara uma variável local a um método é reservado um espaço na [pilha](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101). É reservado um espaço para cada variável e o espaço depende do tamanho do objeto, sendo que os objetos por referência têm o tamanho de um ponteiro. No seu caso só há uma declaração e um espaço. É garantido que cada uma das 10 passadas nesta declaração de variável só precisa de um espaço e não tem porque reservar mais de um espaço para ela.

Da mesma forma que se você tem níveis diferentes de [escopo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/135572/101) só precisa reservar espaço para a maior quantidade de variáveis que existem ao mesmo tempo (considerando seus tamanhos). Então se uma variável é usada em um bloco com escopo definido e depois outra variável é criada em outro bloco distinto e não aninhado, apesar de ter duas declarações de variáveis só é preciso de um espaço para uma das variáveis, mesmo que elas sejam diferentes. O compilador sempre cria o espaço de forma mais otimizada possível. A declaração de variável não é um mecanismo de execução de código, ele é um comando de estruturação de espaço na memória e só precisa fazer isto uma vez no laço. É o mesmo que fazer isto, mas mantendo escopo:

```
double x;
for (int i = 0; i< 10; i++) {
    x = i + 10;
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

Não sei se tem algum meio de mostrar online o Assembly gerado em Java, mas em C++ tem como e vou mostrar como não faz diferença (Java não é diferente do C++):

```
main:
    push    rbx
    mov     ebx, 10
.L2:
    pxor    xmm0, xmm0
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
    cvtsi2sd        xmm0, ebx
    add     ebx, 1
    call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_insert<double>(double)
    cmp     ebx, 20
    jne     .L2
    xor     eax, eax
    pop     rbx
    ret
```

Veja [no **Compiler Explorer**](https://godbolt.org/z/HlLzH8).

```
main:
    push    rbx
    mov     ebx, 10
.L2:
    pxor    xmm0, xmm0
    mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:_ZSt4cout
    cvtsi2sd        xmm0, ebx
    add     ebx, 1
    call    std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_insert<double>(double)
    cmp     ebx, 20
    jne     .L2
    xor     eax, eax
    pop     rbx
    ret
```

Veja [no **Compiler Explorer**](https://godbolt.org/z/2w7n2a).

Note que dá o mesmo código gerado.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Na verdade, o termo correto seria a criação de uma instância da classe double do Java.

Comment: @LucasAugustoCoelhoLopes não exatamente, `double` não é uma classe, mas de fato há a criação de 10 instâncias de um objeto do tipo `double` e todos colocados em apenas uma variável.

Comment: @LucasAugustoCoelhoLopes Seria uma classe se fosse `Double` (com "D" maiúsculo). `double` (com "d" minúsculo) é um tipo primitivo, não uma classe.

Comment: Verdade. Perdão pelo equívoco.

Comment: @Maniero "se confundiram com a ideia de variável e valor." está correto, mas as vezes por ser um usuário novo ele queira saber quantos valores serão criados, entendi dessa forma  e foquei nessa explicação para ser mais didático

Comment: @LuizAugusto na verdade sua resposta não comete o erro das demais, justamente por isso nem responde o que foi perguntado, ele não quer saber o que tem de errado no código, foi um erro de digitação não ter colocado a variável ali. Então não tem um erro porque não responde a pergunta. As pessoas que votaram na resposta provavelmente não leram a pergunta. Ela seria uma ótima resposta se a pergunta fosse qual é o erro no código, e aí eu terai votado nela e nem teria respondido. Aí a pergunta seria ruim e deveria ser fechada. O SOpt tá ficando muito ruim, as pessoas votam sem critério algum mais.

Answer (score -2):

10 vezes, i começa em 0 e vai até menor (<) que 10 ou seja 9

```
i= 0
i= 1
i= 2
i= 3
i= 4
i= 5
i= 6
i= 7
i= 8
i= 9
```

Comment: Mas a pergunta é sobre a variável `x`, não `i`. São as mesmas coisas? Por que?

Comment: Não são a mesma coisa, mas a variável i que determina quantas vezes entrará no loop, e dentro desse loop  a variável x está sendo criada, impressa e removida.

Comment: Então a variável será criada em tempo de execução e não em tempo de compilação?

Comment: toda variável que é instanciada dentro de um FOR ou  de um WHILE tem o ciclo de vida dentro do FOR ou do WHILE