# Sobrecarga de operadores c++

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos, operadores, sobrecarga

Saudações!
Eu preciso fazer a implementação deste método da classe FeetInches.

```
FeetInches operator - (const FeetInches &);
```

Estou me perguntando se faz sentido o parâmetro não ter um nome, apenas o tipo. Se sim, como faço para usar. Abraços.

Comment: Luana, veja a resposta do @Maniero nesta pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136279/qual-a-diferença-entre-declaração-e-definição/136280#136280. 
A instrução apresentada na sua pergunta é uma declaração do operador '-', i.e, a introdução de um identificador e das suas propriedades. Neste caso, está apenas a informar o compilador da existência deste identificador e das suas caracteristicas (recebe uma referência do tipo FeetInches e retorna um objecto do tipo FeetInches), pelo que não é necessário indicar o nome do parâmetro.

Answer (score 0):

Você está a confundir declaração com implementação. Isto aplicado especificamente a métodos ou funções.

Imagine que precisa de uma função que some dois inteiros. Nesse caso você pode algures declarar a função omitindo o nome dos parametros:

```
int soma(int, int);
```

A linha de código anterior indica que existe uma função soma que retorna um inteiro e recebe dois inteiros como parâmetro, mas cuja implementação ainda irá aparecer.

Mais à frente pode implementar a função, dando-lhe o código necessário para que faça o pretendido, e na implementação os nomes dos parâmetros já tem de ser indicados:

```
int soma(int operando1, int operando2){
    return operando1 + operando2;
}
```

Mas note que dependendo da situação, você pode não querer declarar previamente a função e escrever apenas a sua implementação. Existem cenários em que precisa mesmo de declarar previamente, mas numa boa parte deles não.

No seu exemplo apenas tem a declaração, e por isso não é necessário ter o nome. Mas para poder compilar corretamente vai precisar da implementação que inclui o código do método em si. Fazer a declaração e logo a seguir ter a implementação na classe não lhe traz grande vantagem por isso sugiro apenas colocar a implementação, algo como:

```
class FeetInches {
    ... //outros campos e métodos da classe

    FeetInches operator-(const FeetInches &param1){
        ... //codigo que interpreta o param1 e faz a negação/inversão
        return ...; //retornar a nova instância após a operação
    }
};
```

Nota: todos os `...` representam o código especifico da sua implementação, relacionado com o seu objetivo.