# Diferença de desempenho entre biblioteca estática e compartilhada

Tags: c, c++, desempenho, dll, biblioteca

Qual é a melhor em quesito desempenho? Compilar o programa utilizando bibliotecas como o MySQL Connector e SQLite como *static* (ficando dentro do binário compilado) ou como *shared* ficando separada do binário.

Além disso, é possível usar uma biblioteca compartilhada em uma subpasta em vez de ficar junto com o binário executável?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na carga a biblioteca dinâmica terá que montar uma tabela onde as estão disponíveis os símbolos que o código acessará. A diferença é bem pequena e não fará qualquer diferença importante. Pode haver ganho na carga da biblioteca que pode já estar na memória. Como pode economizar consumo de memória, pode haver ganho por ter mais chance de estar em cache.

Pode haver um *overhead* na chamadas das funções, [como demonstra esse teste](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2004-06/msg01956.html).

Em aplicações que usam banco de dados, onde o mínimo acesso é absurdamente mais caro que a carga do executável, não afetará nada de forma significativa.

É possível em algumas situações obter melhor performance por causa de melhor otimização se compilar estaticamente. E pode ter algum ganho pela localidade de referência. Não espere milagres, ou que faça diferença na maioria das aplicações.

Eu particularmente prefiro compilação estática, sempre que possível.

É possível colocar as bibliotecas compiladas em pastas onde o sistema está instruído a procurar por padrão ou que a aplicação saiba de alguma forma que deva buscar nestes locais. Isto costuma ser uma dor de cabeça e hoje evita-se bastante. Não estamos mais em tempo que isto seja uma vantagem.

É melhor deixar as bibliotecas dinâmicas quando é algo que o sistema operacional já tem sem ambiguidade ou se vai criar um sistema de *plugin*/*hot patch*.

[Isso pode ser útil](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44269/101).

Tem mais detalhes sobre o assunto em [Qual a diferença entre linkagem estática e dinâmica?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/149372/101)

Comment: Gostei muito de seu comentário e das referencias, mas tem uma coisa que não sai da minha mente, Uma aplicação usando bibliotecas dinâmica quando for executada ele irá carregar tudo para a memória? A estática também faz isso? Pois como estou desenvolvendo um site completo em C++ não seria carregado todas as páginas para memória? Grato novamente.

Comment: Bom isto já é outra pergunta, mas em geral o sistema operacional só carrega na memória o que é necessário, ou seja carrega a tabela se símbolos e o que for sendo usado.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda.