# Criar um .exe standalone de um game no Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, jogos

Preciso lançar um jogo mas quero criar um .exe autônomo, pois quando o VS termina a compilação cria o .exe mas junto estão as dll do jogo, eu queria que ficasse somente o .exe para poder distribuir. Eu sei que ele ficará mais pesado por isso.

Jogo feito em C++, versão do VS é 2013.

Nesse link uma pessoa responde como fazer mas eu não consegui.

http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/isnt-it-possible-to-create-a-standalone-exe-of-my-game/23765

Sou nova nessa área, então se algum puder me ajudar agradeço muito.

Comment: Depende do que está fazendo. Se está usando bibliotecas externas que são naturalmente separadas não é muito fácil fazer isso (e estou sendo cauteloso, na verdade ninguém faz isso). Se as bibliotecas permitem fazer aí tudo bem. Só que teria que postar um problema específico. Dizer que não está conseguindo fazer, sem dar detalhes, não produzirá boas respostas. Como o que foi postado a melhor resposta que pode obter já está no *link* fornecido.

Comment: Sim são bibliotecas externas e internas.  Mas eu não entendi ao certo de como fazer  o que está link. Seria para postar o jogo no Steam e ele pede que seja um .exe standalone. Eu uso a biblioteca cocos2d-x (dentre outras) como no link.

Comment: Você tem que [edit] a pergunta e colocar detalhes sobre o que está fazendo, caso contrário fica impossível responder. De qualquer forma é pouco provável que o Steam exija isso, tem um monte de jogo que não consegue fazer desta forma e já peguei vários jogos lá que não são assim.

Comment: Jéssica, não vou postar como uma resposta pois não é a sua pergunta, mas ai vai: Um executável Standalone seria qualquer software que não necessita de softwares terceiros (não acoplados) para funcionar. Isto inclui aplicações compiladas, ainda que incluam DLLs terceiras. O que a Steam não aceita no caso são programas interpretados (por exemplo que necessitem da Java Virtual Machine ou de um interpretador Python para funcionar, ou ainda que necessitem de uma biblioteca que não é inclusa no software). Espero ter esclarecido sua dúvida quanto a isto.

Comment: Quanto ao caso de você desejar criar apenas um executável, sem DLLs você deve procurar buscar informações sobre linkagem estática. A maioria dos desenvolvedores de bibliotecas não disponibilizam a opção de linkagem estática (normalmente arquivos .lib), mas disponibilizam DLLs (bibliotecas de linkagem dinâmica). Mais informações a respeito podem ser encontradas nesta pergunta: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44269/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-dll-e-lib

Comment: Bom me desculpem se não consegui passar ao certo meu problema, mas mesmo assim vocês me ajudaram já é muito. Obrigada

Comment: Geralmente vários programas usam dlls, o navegador chrome tem inumeras dlls, jogos como GTA também. O que você precisa é criar um instalador para o game