# Qual a origem dos conflitos entre bibliotecas?

Tags: biblioteca, biblioteca-estática

Estava estudando sobre bibliotecas estáticas e dinâmicas quando li que um dos principais motivos para o uso das dinâmicas é a ocorrência de conflitos entre bibliotecas estáticas, mas qual a origem desses conflitos? Se a pergunta for muito geral, poderiam citar exemplos de situações causadoras de conflitos? Li sobre conflitos em uma resposta aqui do site, nesse [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/44269/qual-a-diferen%C3%A7a-de-dll-e-lib). Em "Guia de escolha pela DLL" está escrito "Linkar estaticamente duas bibliotecas está causando algum conflito ou dificuldade e dinamicamente resolve."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto realmente é raro e ocorre apenas quando o código não possui nenhuma forma de *namespace*, mesmo que informal (ou seja, é código ruim). Se você tem duas bibliotecas estáticas que tem algum símbolo igual presente em ambas não poderá *linkar*. Em algum caso é possível usar isto dinamicamente porque o símbolo presente nas duas DLLs pode não ser usado ao mesmo tempo, então funcionaria. Note que este não é um motivo prevalente, nem é um fortemente adotado, coloquei naquela resposta para completeza de informação, mas não deveria se apegar a isto, os outros motivos são muito mais importantes. E tem outras maneiras de conseguir resolver isto de outras maneiras, melhorando o código, ou usando alguns truques, eu só dei uma opção.

Acredito que até existam alguns casos mais específicos dependente da tecnologia usada, mas nunca tive e não posso falar em específico.