# Aplicação com frontend separado pode ser considerada monolítica?

Tags: java, arquitetura-de-software

Pesquisei bastante mas não consegui sanar essa dúvida que tive ao estudar sobre aplicações monolíticas, quando *backend* e *front* estão isolados.

Tenho uma aplicação X que o frontend e o backend são separados. O backend é um projeto EJB modular (módulo EJB, módulo business, ...) feito em Java, e o *frontend* é apartado, feito por exemplo com React.

Sabendo que uma aplicação monolítica é quando todas as funcionalidades e códigos estão em um único processo:

1 - Eu posso chamar a aplicação X como um toda de monolítica? Tanto se o *back* e *front* estiverem em uma mesma máquina compartilhando os recursos delas, mas em processos separados, ou cada um em um servidor diferente? Acredito que não, mas não obtive a certeza.

2 - Posso chamar o meu *backend* de monolítico? Ou não, ao se referir a ele devo dizer que é apenas um projeto modular?

Comment: as literaturas (li no wiki, medium, docs.microsoft, etc) diz que uma aplicação monolítica contém "todas as camadas juntas", ou seja, segundo as literaturas **não** pode ser considerada monolítica, uma vez que tem front/back separados. Agora, se olhar para o back todo como uma aplicação, por exemplo ele tem endpoints, api ou outra interface que permita utilizá-lo, poderia ser entendido como uma aplicação, e o front end como outra, dai seria uma mononítico, mas não acho que vai ter uma resposta acertiva pra isso, mas se seguir o conceito, a literatura, não é uma aplicação monolítica

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depende do contexto que está usando o termo. Ele é usado de maneiras diferentes.

Não vou falar de todos contextos porque alguns não fariam sentido.

## Distribuição de executável

Dentro do conceito original, e que parece ser o que a pergunta quer saber, pelo menos no começo, o fato de ter mais de um arquivo executável já não é monolítico. Ou seja, se você tem um monte de *script* em PHP, JavaScript, Python ou outras linguagens, ou DLLs ou algo semelhante geradas com Java, C#, C++, ou outras linguagens, então você já não tem um monólito. Veja mais em [Qual a diferença de DLL e lib?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/44269/101).

Então ter algo rodando em camadas diferentes certamente não tem uma solução monolítica. Mas se considerar só uma parte aí pode ter um monólito só nessa parte, o que pode ocorrer fácil no *backend* e hoje é possível ter no *frontend*, ainda que pouco provável, ou perto do impossível, se considerar que você precisa de pelo menos um HTML e mais alguma coisa para ter algo útil.

Mas isso é até complicado classificar porque a ideia original só pensava em executável. Não sei se o conceito se aplica.

De qualquer forma rodar em processos separados ou não, define nada, porque o monólito tem a ver com o arquivo que é distribuído. Se tiver processos iguais mas existem arquivos diferentes não é monólito, e se tiver mais de um processo iniciado com o mesmo arquivo único, então é.

Rodar na mesma máquina não faz algo ser um monólito, mas se algo roda em outra certamente não é, porque já existem partes.

## Padrão arquitetural

Se quer falar de monolítico em oposição à arquitetura de microsserviços, então sim, não só pode, como é. Ter uma parte *frontend* e *backend* não significa que essas partes são microsserviços.

Quase ninguém entende o que são microsserviços, e menos ainda as pessoas sabem que fazer isso é extremamente difícil e paga-se um preço muito alto, e por isso "ninguém" deve tentar fazer algo assim. O melhor que pode acontecer é a pessoa fazer executáveis separados e dizer que já está na moda, e ter pouco ou nenhum ganho, e a arquitetura continuar sendo monolítica. Mas pode fazer de fato microsserviços e cria um pesadelo para a vida.

Então precisa saber que conceito está falando. Se está falando em ser modular aí o assunto já é arquitetura, e mesmo algo modular ainda é um monólito, a não ser que os serviços separados, e portanto modulares, sejam completamente independentes, o que é muito difícil fazer, e quase ninguém precisa. Modular é algo bom na maioria dos cenários. Quando você tem um *frontend* e um *backend* separado alguma modularidade já obteve.

O *frontend* é completamente independente? Se for então ele é um serviço que não faz parte de um monólito. Provavelmente você tem algo híbrido que em determinada parte tem um serviço separado. E a relação entre as partes é muito simples, o que torna algo viável de ser gerenciado pela maioria dos programadores. Mas é difícil fazer algo ser completamente independente, e o será só em determinado momento e que faça sincronização quando for possível, o que é ainda mais difícil de fazer certo. Fuja dessas coisas. Opte pelo monólito a não ser que você seja um engenheiro muito experiente, tenha uma equipe enorme e uma necessidade extraordinária para adotar algo diferente. A maioria dos engenheiros que optam por microsserviços são só um pouco experientes, se eles fossem mais, não optariam (salvo raríssimas exceções).

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação detalhada. Só não entendi essa parte:
"O frontend é completamente independente? Se for então ele é um serviço que não faz parte de um monólito. Provavelmente você tem algo híbrido que em determinada parte tem um serviço separado."

R: Ele necessita dos dados do backend. O frontend chama os serviços REST do backend, recebe o retorno em JSON, renderiza a página e retorna para o usuário. O que você quis dizer com ter algo híbrido nessa aplicação WEB?

Comment: Então, isso eu acho controverso. Porque raramente existem algo tão independentes que não depende de mais nada. A questão talvez passe por ele funcionar ainda que seja com limitações Outra interpretação é ele ter como dependência só o que fornece o que ele precisa sem nada a mais. Híbrido que é uma parte é de um jeito e outra parte é de outro jeito..